# Adding properties file to java classpath at runtime

Tags: java

My code generates few properties file at runtime and these will be used by other portion of code.But the other portion of code expects that those properties files in the classpath.

Is there any way to generate the files in classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create empty files which are set on the classpath up front and the application appends to these as necessary.

I'm wondering though, do you need to touch the hard disk at all? Could you not use a cache instead?